# Noun for "identifying with someone"

Tags: word-choice

What is a noun for *identifying with someone*? In Hebrew there is quite a good word for it.

I'm not looking for *sympathy* or *empathy*, but a proposed definition of *sympathy* does reflect my intent although the use of the word seems misleading:

> Agree with a sentiment or opinion

or

> Sharing the thoughts of someone (not with someone)

Comment: Might I ask what the Hebrew word is?

Comment: הזדהות Pronounced "Eez-duh-hoot", which could stand for identification, but also for this purpose.

Answer (score 5):

I think *sympathy* and *empathy* are actually quite good choices in many contexts, but there’s also *like-mindedness*, *compatibility*, and a number of others depending on what you’re going for.

It may be more idiomatic to say that two people are *of one mind* or *on the same page* about a particular topic or interest.

Based on what you’re trying to translate, I think *identification* actually *is* what you’re looking for. It’s a literal translation of הזדהות, and it can refer to the *emotional* experience of identifying with someone or something, as well as the mundane meaning of a driver’s license or other form of personal identification. Its use is largely confined to the latter definition, however, so one of the other terms is probably a better fit.

Answer (score 4):

How about ***likemindedness*** (also *like-mindedness*)?

These aren't nouns, but you can also describe someone as being ***on the same page*** as someone else or ***simpatico*** with someone else.